# Classifying a set of time series with restrictions on the classes

Tags: classification, time-series, prediction

I have $N$ time series, each having $T$ time points, with the class of each time series known. There are $K$ different classes. I want to predict the classes for a set of $M$ time series (with time points possibly different from $T$) with the restriction that the amongst these $M$ time series, the number of series that should belong to each of the $K$ classes is fixed beforehand.

I am entirely new to both time series and classification and any help or insight will be highly appreciated. If a source for dealing with this kind of a problem is available, I would be grateful if you could direct me to it.

Comment: This seems to be kind of a difficult problem on top of standard approaches. what have you tried ?